# How to use SSISDeploy command in powershell script

Tags: powershell, ssis

I'm running `SSISDeploy` command (documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-standalone?view=sql-server-ver15#ssisdeployexe)) in my `CMD`:

```
SSISDeploy.exe -s:"download\Integration Services.ispac" -d:catalog;/SSISDB/TEST/DEVOPS;"TEST03,1234" -at:win
```

all working good, and now I need to run it thought `powershell` script (against `windows server 2019` slave), so I tried this syntax:

```
$SSISDeploy = Start-Process -FilePath SSISDeploy.exe -ArgumentList '/source:"download\Integration Services.ispac"',"/destination:catalog;${Target};"${Env}"" -at:win -wait -PassThru -Credential $cred -RedirectStandardOutput ssisstdout.txt -RedirectStandardError ssisstderr.txt
```

but it fails with exception:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'TEST03,1234'.
+ ... SISDeploy = Start-Process -FilePath SSISDeploy.exe -ArgumentList '/so ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Can you suggest what's wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$StartProcessProps = @{
    FilePath               = 'SSISDeploy.exe'
    ArgumentList          = '-s:"download\Integration Services.ispac" -d:catalog;{0};{1} -at:win' -f $Target, $Env
    Wait                   = $true
    PassThru               = $true
    Credential             = $cred
    RedirectStandardOutput = 'ssisstdout.txt'
    RedirectStandardError  = 'ssisstderr.txt'
}
$SSISDeploy = Start-Process @StartProcessProp
```